# Modelling an elevator using Object-Oriented Analysis and Design

Tags: oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic

There are a set of questions that seem to be commonly-used in interviews and classes when it comes to object-oriented design and analysis. This is one of them; unfortunately, my OOP professor in college never actually gave an answer to it, and so I've been wondering.

The problem is as follows: design a basic set of objects/methods to be used to simulate an elevator bank. What are the objects and their attributes/methods?

For the sake of argument, let us assume that our building has twenty floors; the bottom floor is the lobby, and the second floor connects to the parking garage (therefore, people will enter/exit the building on either the bottom floor or the second floor). There is one elevator bank that services all the floors; there are three elevator shafts in the elevator bank, and one elevator per shaft.

What would be the correct way to model this in an object-oriented model?

Comment: This is my favorite interview question.  It is simple to ask but surprisingly complex to get right.  It involves things like queues and can easily be extended to throw in more challenges.  For example, how would you optimize the algorithm to reduce wait times.

Comment: Yea, it's a really great open-ended question. Never got asked that one, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 177, accepted):

First there is an elevator class. It has a direction (up, down, stand, maintenance), a current floor and a list of floor requests sorted in the direction. It receives request from this elevator.

Then there is a bank. It contains the elevators and receives the requests from the floors. These are scheduled to all active elevators (not in maintenance).

The scheduling will be like:

- if available pick a standing elevator for this floor.
- else pick an elevator moving to this floor.
- else pick a standing elevator on an other floor.
- else pick the elevator with the lowest load.

Each elevator has a set of states.

- Maintenance: the elevator does not react to external signals (only to its own signals).
- Stand: the elevator is fixed on a floor. If it receives a call. And the elevator is on that floor, the doors open. If it is on another floor, it moves in that direction.
- Up: the elevator moves up. Each time it reaches a floor, it checks if it needs to stop. If so it stops and opens the doors. It waits for a certain amount of time and closes the door (unless someting is moving through them. Then it removes the floor from the request list and checks if there is another request. If so the elevator starts moving again. If not it enters the state stand.
- Down: like up but in reverse direction.

There are additional signals:

- alarm. The elevator stops. And if it is on a floor, the doors open, the request list is cleared, the requests moved back to the bank.
- door open. Opens the doors if an elevator is on a floor and not moving.
- door closes. Closed the door if they are open.

EDIT:
Some elevators don't start at bottom/first_floor esp. in case of skyscrapers.

min_floor & max_floor are two additional attributes for Elevator.

Comment: Elevator simulation http://play.elevatorsaga.com/

Comment: Seems like this scheduling approach is missing some optimizations, for example, if an elevator is already going to a floor where a person has requested an elevator, then there is no need to schedule another elevator to come.

Comment: Would the receiving request and scheduling be synchronous or asynchronous ? If async then how would we achieve that ?

Comment: I took a stab at it some years ago, including some of the mentioned optimizations: 
https://github.com/samsonradu/elevator/blob/gh-pages/js/src/stores/elevator.js

DEMO: http://samsonradu.github.io/elevator/

Answer (score 21):

Donald Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming Vol.1 has a demonstration of elevator and the data-structures. Knuth presents a very thorough discussion and program.

Knuth(1997) "Information Structures", *The Art of Computer Programming* Vol. 1 [pp.302-308](http://books.google.com/books?id=MooMkK6ERuYC&lpg=PA304&dq=knuth%20elevator&pg=PA302#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: linked to google books above.

Comment: This section of the book describes (in details) how to run an elevator simulation. It does NOT describe how to model it (in an OOP way). But yeah..great book!

Answer (score 19):

I've seen many variants of this problem. One of the main differences (that determines the difficulty) is whether there is some centralized attempt to have a "smart and efficient system" that would have load balancing (e.g., send more idle elevators to lobby in morning). If that is the case, the design will include a whole subsystem with really fun design.

A full design is obviously too much to present here and there are many altenatives.  The breadth is also not clear. In an interview, they'll try to figure out how you would think. However, these are some of the things you would need:

1. Representation of the central controller (assuming there is one).
2. Representations of elevators
3. Representations of the interface units of the elevator (these may be different from 
   elevator to elevator). Obviously also call buttons on every floor, etc.
4. Representations of the arrows or indicators on each floor (almost a "view" of the elevator model).
5. Representation of a human and cargo (may be important for factoring in maximal loads)
6. Representation of the building (in some cases, as certain floors may be blocked at times, etc.)

Answer (score 9):

See:

```
Lu Luo, A UML Documentation for a Elevator System
Distributed Embedded Systems, Fall 2000
Ph.D. Project Report
Carneghie Mellon University
```

[link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CHYQFjAE&url=http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~luluo/Courses/18540PhDreport.pdf&ei=zXu_UPbNKuveigKl1oDwCw&usg=AFQjCNGC5qPKgAg6ILn1KNOu782rpjEK3g&sig2=j4VTUJCoyWHY6T_lkzV0-w)

Answer (score 5):

Detailed Answer:

http://www.angelfire.com/trek/software/elevator.html

Answer (score 2):

Thing's to be Consider While [Designing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fITuhLSwbt8) the Elevator System,

```
Elevator
Floor/Location Identifier
Number of steps
Rotation speed
Daterange
InstallationDate
MaintainenceDate
Department Identifier
AllowedWeight
Detail / Description
Poison Ratio (Statistics)
Start
Stop
SetDirection
SetRotationSpeed
EmergencyStop = Stop + Alert
EmergencyAccidentSenser Handler
```

Each button press results in an elevator request which has to be served. Each of these requests is tracked at a global place

The number of elevators in the building will be determined by the user. The building will contain a fixed number of floors. The number of passengers that can fit into the elevator will be fixed. The passengers will be counted as they leave the elevator at their destination floor. The destination floor will be determined using a "random" Poisson interval. When all of the passengers in the elevator have reached their destination floors, the elevator will return to the lobby to pickup more passengers

Answer (score 2):

Main thing to worry about is how would you notify the elevator that it needs to move up or down. and also if you are going to have a centralized class to control this behavior and how could you distribute the control.

It seems like it can be very simple or very complicated. If we don't take concurrency or the time for an elevator to get to one place, then it seems like it will be simple since we just need to check the states of elevator, like is it moving up or down, or standing still. But if we make Elevator implement Runnable, and constantly check and synchronize a queue (linkedList). A Controller class will assign which floor to go in the queue. When the queue is empty, the run() method will wait (queue.wait() ), when a floor is assigned to this elevator, it will call queue.notify() to wake up the run() method, and run() method will call goToFloor(queue.pop()). This will make the problem too complicated. I tried to write it on paper, but dont think it works. It seems like we don't really need to take concurrency or timing issue into account here, but we do need to somehow use a queue to distribute the control.

Any suggestion?